# Use ?: Operand on entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I want to use it in this way

```
Context.Moves.OfType<Cuotes>().Where(p =>
                p.Final == true
                && dtFrom.DateTime != null ? p.DeliverDate >= dtFrom.DateTime : true
                && dtTo.DateTime != null ? p.DeliverDate <= dtToHasta.DateTime : true
                && !ckShowDelivered.Checked ? p.Delivered == false : true
                && !ckShowDelivered.Checked ? p.Canceled == false : true
                );
```

Due I have muliple filters I tried to manipulate in this way, actually I have another checkbox to condition if old `Cuotes` versions are showed with `Final == false` statement, but this operand inside the `Where` clause seems to be not working.

It is a way to apply this operand or I must to hard code the if conditions for each combination of options posible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just chain those in separate `Where` calls:

```
var result = Context.Moves.OfType<Cuotes>().Where(p => p.Final == true);

if (dtFrom.DateTime != null)
    result = result.Where(p => p.DeliverDate >= dtFrom.DateTime);
if (dtTo.DateTime != null)
    result = result.Where(p => p.DeliverDate <= dtToHasta.DateTime);
if (!ckShowDelivered.Checked)
    result = result.Where(p => !p.Delivered);
if (!ckShowDelivered.Checked)
    result = result.Where(p => !p.Canceled);
```

That way, you can use any kind of external conditions to affect your query without having to use those external conditions within the query itself.